# For NimbusKit NIToolbarPhotoViewController is there a way to set zoom scale

Tags: ios, xcode, nimbus, nimbus-ios

I'm using NIToolbarPhotoViewController by subclassing it.  So far everything is working, but i can not change max zoom scale like you can with scroll views.  I'm set

```
photoAlbumView.zoomingAboveOriginalSizeIsEnabled = YES
```

and

photoAlbumView.pagingScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 100

But that didn't seen to do anything.  It's still using the default zoom factor i think it's around 2, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting maximumScale to 100 on the returned view in the pageViewForIndex data source method.

The problem you're seeing is that the maximumScale is set on the individual photo view. The paging scroll view is simply what contains and manages the multiple pages of photos.